# RegEx match containing certain extensions but allow query parameters to be included

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex to match all URLs which contain (allowed extensions) (regex at the bottom)

It should also include those URLs that :

contain query parameters:

`example.com/file.pdf?cb=1625595`

AND OR

contain number (#) sign:

```
example.com/myfile.pdf?cb=1625595#page=4
example.com/myfile.pdf#page=4
```

for example:

```
example.com  NO MATCH 
example.com/file.pdf?cb=1625595 MATCH
example.com/SLmj24.msp MATCH
example.com/Disclosure.pdf?cb=1625595 MATCH
example.com/myfile.pdf#page=4 MATCH
example.com/myfile.pdf?cb=1625595#page=4 MATCH
example.com/?cb=1625595 NO MATCH
```

This is what I have for the extension, I just need to add the second part (query parameters if they exist and number sign if it exists)

```
^.*\.(7z|aac|arc|arj|asf|asx|avi|bin|csv|doc|exe|flv|gif|gz|gzip|hqx|jar|jpe?g|js|mp(2|3|4|e?g)|mov(ie)?|msi|msp|pdf|phps|png|ppt|qtm?|ra(m|r)?|sea|sit|tar|tgz|torrent|txt|wav|wma|wmv|wpd|xls|xml|z|zip)$
```

Comment: example.com/myfile.pdf#page=4 does not match any of the three conditions. Why does it match at your showcase? Should also number sign # followed by string without query parameters be allowed?

Comment: Hello, that example should also match just because its has .pdf extension, because the query parameter doesn't always exist in the site. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to add that I want the regex to fire up whenever there's an allowed extension, for the other conditions they can only fire up if they have .ext included (ie.   .pdf   .doc) but not without any extension.

Comment: The post was confusing, I have made edits. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may add `(?:$|[#?])` after the end of your pattern:

```js
^.*\.(7z|aac|arc|arj|asf|asx|avi|bin|csv|doc|exe|flv|gif|gz|gzip|hqx|jar|jpe?g|js|mp([234]|e?g)|mov(ie)?|msi|msp|pdf|phps|png|ppt|qtm?|ra[mr]?|sea|sit|tar|tgz|torrent|txt|wav|wma|wmv|wpd|xls|xml|z|zip)(?:$|[#?])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GCc8dw/1).

The `(?:$|[#?])` part matches either end of string (requiring the end of string at the currently matched position) or a `#` or `?` char.

Note I converted some group alternatives into character classes, `(2|3|4|e?g)` to `([234]|e?g)` and `(m|r)?` to `[mr]?` as this is best practice.